# print elements in list as concatenated string

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

I have a simple dictionary:

```
convert = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3, 'd' : 4}
```

and list

```
letters = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

I want to iterate over each element in the list, and use it as a lookup in my dictionary, and print the value **as a concatenated string**. I'm using:

```
for c in letters:
    print convert[c],
```

which outputs:

```
1 2 3 4
```

How can I remove the spaces (in v.2.7.10) in the print statement to get:

```
1234
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with a generator expression.
Note that you have to explicitly convert to `str` when using this method:

```
convert = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3, 'd' : 4}
letters = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
print ''.join(str(convert[c]) for c in letters)
>> 1234
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to do it using an explicit `for` loop, you can create a list of strings, appending to that and calling `join` outside the loop. I'm using a list since it is more efficient because strings are immutable:

```
output_list = []
for c in letters:
    # do other stuff
    output_list.append(str(convert[c]))
print ''.join(output_list)
```

Comment: @fugu the loop is within the `join` function call

Comment: @m_callens - But what if I wanted to do this within a larger loop through the `characters` in `letters`?

Comment: I'm amazed you can't just print a single character at a time while iterating over a string!

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to `print` only and you don't need the end result, then you can use the `arg` of [`print`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) method:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> for c in letters:
        print(convert[c], sep='', end='')


1234
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after - I thought that `end=''` was a feature of Python 3 though?

Comment: OP is using Python 2. This would only work if doing `from _future_ import print_function`.

Comment: @DeepSpace...yea...forget to add the import

Comment: @fugu...This is a feature of Python3, that's why you will need the `import` expression

Answer (score 1):

Try this out :-

```
>>> convert = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3, 'd' : 4}
>>> letters = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
>>> result = ''
>>> for i in letters:
        result += str(convert[i])  # Since you want concatenated string
>>> print result
'1234'
```

Or using list comprehension :-

```
>>> convert = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3, 'd' : 4}
>>> letters = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
>>> ''.join([str(convert[i]) for i in letters])
'1234'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the extra spaces introduced by `print` you could write data to standard output using `sys.stdout.write()`:

```
In [55]: letters = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

In [56]: convert = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3, 'd' : 4}

In [57]: import sys

In [58]: for letter in letters: sys.stdout.write(convert[letter])
1234
```

As a side note, most of the solutions proposed here (mine included) produce the expected output for the input data you provided, but see what happens if `letters` contains a letter (such as `'e'`) that is not a key in `convert`:

```
In [59]: letters = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')

In [60]: print ''.join(str(convert[letter]) for letter in letters)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-60-da3963dcc14b>", line 1, in <module>
    print ''.join(str(convert[letter]) for letter in letters)

  File "<ipython-input-60-da3963dcc14b>", line 1, in <genexpr>
    print ''.join(str(convert[letter]) for letter in letters)

KeyError: 'e'
```

To avoid this, I recommend you to use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict.get#dict.get) as this method returns a default value (`''` in the example below) instead of raising an error when the key is not in the dictionary:

```
In [61]: print ''.join(str(convert.get(letter, '')) for letter in letters)
1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add an alternative that uses `reduce`, although it's not necessarily more readable, it may be more flexible later on. If you need to change the code to do something else, you can just adjust the `lambda` function:

```
>>> print reduce(lambda x,y: str(x)+str(y),[convert[z] for z in letters])
1234
```

or to be more readable:

```
>>> def concat_letters(x,y):
    return str(x)+str(y)

>>> print reduce(concat_letters,[convert[z] for z in letters])
1234
```

Comment: Python 3 users will need to add `from functools import reduce`